# HandsOnTable (Vue Wrapper) - Associate row with database id?

Tags: vue.js, handsontable

I'm trialling HandsOnTable via the Vue wrapper to make a simple database editor. I can populate the table easily, however I now need to save changes back to the database.

If I use the afterChange() method hot will give me the changes in the cells that have changed, however I need to be able to associate those changes with a database id to send them back to the server. Any idea of how to do this, and also is it possible to get the changes associated with a row? Would it also be possible to do this without displaying the database id to the user in the table?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question, you can associate metadatas to cells. So you can put your technical id in your first column for example or a hidden column (or whereever you want).

```
hot.setCellMeta(0, 0, 'myIdName', 'myIdValue');
```

where "hot" is your Handsontable instance. ([documentation reference](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/Core.html#setCellMeta))

You can then access `getCellMeta(0, 0)`.

---

Second question :

> and also is it possible to get the changes associated with a row ?

You already are able to get the changes of specific rows by filter the changes in the `afterChange` hook. Taking [the example from Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/Hooks.html#event:afterChange) documentation this is how you get the row :

```
new Handsontable(element, {
  afterChange: (changes) => {
    changes.forEach(([row, prop, oldValue, newValue]) => {
      // Some logic...
    });
  }
})
```

As you can see changes is an array of change that contain row and col (prop).

Hope this helps.